# How do I get a new value from the same JavaScript function each time I use it?

Tags: javascript, function

This question is directly related to [The Odin Project Rock Paper Scissors JavaScript Fundamentals course](https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/foundations/courses/foundations/lessons/rock-paper-scissors).

I have successfully made a function which randomly picks "rock," "paper," or "scissors" for the computer, called "computerPlay."

```
    function computerPlay() {
    const gameArray = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameArray.length);
    return gameArray[random];
 }
```

I have made another function to accept the player's input of "rock," "paper," "scissors" (or 1, 2, 3 respectively) with no respect for casing in another function, called "playerPlay."

```
function playerPlay() {
   console.log ("Do you choose 'Rock' (1), 'Paper' (2), or 'Scissors' (3)?");
   let playerChoice = prompt("Do you choose 'Rock' (1), 'Paper' (2), or 'Scissors' (3)?");
   if (playerChoice.toLowerCase() === "rock" || parseInt(playerChoice) === 1) {
      playerChoice = "Rock";
   } else if (playerChoice.toLowerCase() === "paper" || parseInt(playerChoice) === 2) {
      playerChoice = "Paper";
   }
   else if (playerChoice.toLowerCase() === "scissors" || parseInt(playerChoice) === 3) {
      playerChoice = "Scissors";
   }
   else if (playerChoice.toLowerCase() !== "rock" || "scissors" || "paper" || parseInt(playerChoice) !== 1 || 2 || 3) {
      alert("Please try to enter your value again :)")
      playerSelection();
   }
   else {
      console.log("Not sure what's going on, hold on to yer butts ;)")
   }
   return playerChoice;
}
```

The function playerPlay() is saved into the const variable playerSelection, and the frunction computerPlay() is saved into the const variable computerSelection.

```
 // Create a variable to store player's choice
 const playerSelection = playerPlay();

 // Create a variable to store computer's choice
 const computerSelection = computerPlay();
```

These two const variables are then used in the playRound() function which runs a set of comparisons to see and then console.log and return whether the player or computer won the round of rock, papers, scissors.

```
/* Write a function that plays a single round of Rock Paper Scissors. The function should take two parameters - the playerSelection and 
computerSelection - and then return a string that declares the winner of the round like so: "You Lose! Paper beats Rock" */

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
   if (computerSelection.toLowerCase() === playerSelection.toLowerCase()) {
      console.log("It's a draw!");
      return("Your Choice: " + playerSelection + ". " + "Computer: " + computerSelection);
   } else if (computerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors") {
      console.log("Rock beats scissors! You lose :(");
      return("Your Choice: " + playerSelection + ". " + "Computer: " + computerSelection);
   } else if (computerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock") {
      console.log("Rock beats scissors! You win :D");
      return("Your Choice: " + playerSelection + ". " + "Computer: " + computerSelection);
   } else if (computerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper") {
      console.log("Scissors beats paper! You lose :(");
      return("Your Choice: " + playerSelection + ". " + "Computer: " + computerSelection);
   } else if (computerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissors") {
      console.log("Scissors beats paper! You win :D");
      return("Your Choice: " + playerSelection + ". " + "Computer: " + computerSelection);
   } else if (computerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock") {
      console.log("Paper beats rock! You lose :(");
      return("Your Choice: " + playerSelection + ". " + "Computer: " + computerSelection);
   } else if (computerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock" && playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper") {
      console.log("Paper beats rock! You win :D");
      return("Your Choice: " + playerSelection + ". " + "Computer: " + computerSelection);
   } else {
      console.log("I'm not sure what, but something went worng :(");
   }
}
```

My issue comes from when I need to repeat the playRound() function 5 times, and have each round be different.

```
/* Write a NEW function called game(). Use the previous function inside of this one to play a 5 round game that keeps score and reports 
a winner or loser at the end. */
// Define function / rule for winning and keeping track of score and determining winner for 5 rounds of game
// Make each round reset the computer choice and get new input from the player.

function game() {
   roundOne;
   roundTwo;
   roundThree;
   roundFour;
   roundFive;
}

const roundOne = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
const roundTwo = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
const roundThree = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
const roundFour = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
const roundFive = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);

// Print results of game round
console.log(game(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

I recently tried to make 5 new const variables (roundOne, roundTwo... roundFive) to contain the "playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);" function. I tried also changing the playerSelection and computerSelection const variables to let, thinking the const nature could be locking the values in place until I reload the page. I thought it might be a scope issue, but I am not understanding where exactly it is -- which is why I thought to ask here. The main issue is that the player-entered value and the computer randomly-generated value are always the same for the 5 repeated rounds. How do I get a different value to print for each repeated round? Does it maybe have to do with how I use "gameArray" (in computerPlay() function) and "playerChoice" (in playerPlay() function)?

I apologize if this much longer than it needs to be. I will continue looking into things as well. Thank you very much in advance.

(This is my first actual JavaScript creation/project of any kind, so any feedback in general, or in how I posted/asked this question as well, would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to yield value multiple times from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244150/how-to-yield-value-multiple-times-from-function)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you only set your consts `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` once (and they are consts, so can't be modified). You then pass these into your `playRound` function which processes the same consts 5 times. Consider removing these consts altogether and writing your game function like this:

```
function game() {
   //Play game 5 times
   for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     const playerSelection = playerPlay();
     const computerSelection = computerPlay();
     // Call playRound function, passing in newly returned values
     // from the playerPlay and computerPlay functions
     const currentRound = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
     // Log our result
     console.log(currentRound);
   }
}
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
function game() {
   //Play game 5 times
   for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     // Call playRound function, passing in newly returned values
     // from the playerPlay and computerPlay functions and log to console
     console.log(playRound(playerPlay(), computerPlay()));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! +1 To confirm: was `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` being defined as const variables a global scope issue? And so by defining `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` within the `game()` function's loop it makes it so that a new value is returned each time because of the internal scope? (i.e., that `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` only have values within the loop, and so change each time they call the `playerPlay()` and `computerPlay()` functions because those are global scope?)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You defined your `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` at a global scope, and only once. So whenever you referenced them anywhere else in your code you were using that one and only instantiation of them. I defined them inside the loop, so (as you correctly stated in your comment), they are defined for use in a single iteration of the loop only, then destroyed. Then with my second example, I didn't even bother assigning the result of the functions to a variable at all as there isn't much point saving them in memory for them to be destroyed a clock tick later